# Order process using SignalR asp.net core best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Below is the order process which i have implemented thorough `signalR` in `asp.net core web api`. Every thing is working fine except one scenario(**Problem scenario given below**) i need the best possible solution.

[image: Figure-System Overview]

System Overview:

1)  Customer Place new order (Client wait until order being processed by admin client).

2)  The order is saved to the DB with ‘status=unknown ‘.

3)  Admin is notified through hub about new order. (on a dashboard)

4)  Admin accepts or decline new order then Order status is updated in database.

5)  Customer is notified about the order, if is accepted or declined through SignalR

**Problem scenario**

The business rule that we have to implement is that the order should be automatically declined after 2 minutes if the Admin does not respond. In this case the server should automatically decline the order and the customer should be notified.

**Solution 1**: We thought of adding a timer on the Customer and Admin side, but we prefer the Timer to be somewhere on the server so we don't have to implement the timers on the customer and admin side.

**Base Hub Controller**

```
 public abstract class ApiHubController<T> : Controller
    where T : Hub
{
    private readonly IHubContext _hub;
    public IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients { get; private set; }
    public IGroupManager Groups { get; private set; }
    protected ApiHubController(IConnectionManager signalRConnectionManager)
    {
        var _hub = signalRConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>();
        Clients = _hub.Clients;
        Groups = _hub.Groups;
    }
}

public class BaseHubController : ApiHubController<Broadcaster>
{




    public BaseHubController(IConnectionManager signalRConnectionManager) : base(signalRConnectionManager)
    {

    }


}
```

**Server side code (Place Order)**

```
  public class OrderController : BaseHubController
     {

       public async Task SendNotification([FromBody]NotificationDTO notify)
        {
            await Clients.Group(notify.AdminId.ToString()).SendNotificationToDashboard(notify); //notifing to admin for about //new order 
        }

        public async Task NotifyDashboard(NotificationDTO model) 
        {
            var sendNotification = SendNotification(model);//sending notification to admin dashboard  


        }

          [HttpPost]
        [Route("PlaceOrder")]
         public IActionResult PlaceOrder([FromBody]OrderDTO order)//Coustomer place order
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
            }


            var orderCode = _orderProvider.PlaceOrder(order,  ValidationContainer);//save new order in database
            var notify = order.GetNotificationModel();
            notify.OrderId = orderCode;
            NotifyDashboard(notify);
            //Other code

            return new OkObjectResult(new { OrderCode = orderCodeString, OrderId = orderCode });
        }   


    }
```

Comment: Why would you need a timer on the client if the server can notify the client of failure?

Comment: in the fetch for the admin screen.... check all orders... and then update those out of date and display those which are OK. If order is left open on Admin screen.. do check before.. proceeding and notify admin if it was out of date.

Comment: @stuartd because if admin is not connected at time when order placed so we thought of adding timer to decline order after 2mins

Comment: @Seabizkit kindly read problem statement

Comment: @usmanlqbal I see... sorry, best is create a service which runs independently, agreed-ed don't do this with client timers.

Comment: So create a separate service to handle the expired orders, then create another table for notifications... add to these.... when they expire. Now when the clients do request, create an ajax request to check for notifications, once the notification is read, remove it. The notification table will need to be user specific, which the hub detects that they are no longer online, then remove the notification. Please bare in mind i know this is not perfect.